# How to dynamically change TextSize of TextView in ListView after initial load

Tags: android, listview, textview, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListView` that uses a `SimpleCursorAdapater` to pull data from an `SQLlite` database to populate a `TextView` in the `ListView`.

I am enabling the user to increase or decrease the `TextSize` of the `TextView` in the `ListView` dynamically at runtime - not everyone can read the standard font size without glasses and sometimes folks don't have their readers with them.

The only way I have found to do this is to refetch the cursor; call `changeCursor()` on the adapter; and use the viewBinder to modify the TextSize as shown below.

It works - but surely this is not the correct/most-efficient way to do this - it seems I should be able to do this without fetching a new cursor to trigger the viewBinder when someone chooses to increase/decrease the font size. Can someone show me how it should be done?

Here's the code I use now...

Select menu item to increase font size...

```
TextSize++;
new UpdateListViewCursor().execute();   // extends AsyncTask
```

`UpdateListViewCursor()` - requires fetching new cursor

```
private class UpdateListViewCursor extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Cursor> {

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // fetch checklist table data anew
        return CreateChecklistCursor(checklistDbHelper.getReadableDatabase());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) {
        super.onPostExecute(cursor);
        // update adapter
        dataAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
    }
```

`ViewBinder()` code

```
@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    ((TextView) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (float) TextSize);
}
```

Comment: Since you are using sp, just stick to the guidelines of material design for text sizes. If the text is too small for an user, he can make the whole system font bigger through settings. You probably shouldn't worry about this on your app.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Natan. However, it is my single biggest requested feature from my users. So I need to provide it.

Comment: Why are you refetching the cursor? Just call notifyDataSetChanged() method in adapter

Comment: Thank you. That's the piece I needed.